# JtwitterThis element neither has attached source nor attached javadoc and hence no javadoc could be found

Tags: android

I downloaded 3 different versions of jtwitter for my Yamba app yet when I mouse on any jtwitter function like "Twitter" it displays "This element neither has attached source nor attached javadoc and hence no javadoc could be found" and it closes forcefully at runtime,What do I do...I use Eclipse Juno and ADT 20v2

Comment: Or where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (documented) source code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/winterstein/JTwitter).

You can clone (or download) it and "compile" your own documentation for it using the [JavaDoc](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/javadoc/#section4_0) tool bundled with your JDK.